# How to remove the extra column while freezing in jxl api?

Tags: excel, jxl

Using jxl, I'm trying to do both horizontal and vertical freeze :

```
sheet.getSettings().setVerticalFreeze(7);
sheet.getSettings().setHorizontalFreeze(1);
```

The horizontal one is fine, but the vertical one adds an extra column (narrow column).  Not only that - if I open up the excel file, unfreeze all columns, and try to freeze again manually, it adds the extra column again !!  Something gets messed up, while the file is generated.

Any idea how to fix this?

I'm on Mac, and using MS office on mac

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it is a bug in Mac Excel.  It works correctly in windows :)